# Nullable object must have a value?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, exception, nullable

On the line: `bool travel = fill.travel.Value;` I am getting the following error:

> Nullable object must have a value

and i am not sure why. All I want to do is get the value in the database of travel which is currently false. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    var fill = (from f in db.expenseHdrs
                where f.rptNo == getPkRowReport()
                select f).FirstOrDefault();

    txtReportDesc.Text = fill.description;
    txtPeriod.Text = fill.period;
    txtPurpose.Text = fill.purpose;

    bool travel = fill.travel.Value;
    chkTravel.Checked = travel 
 }
```

Comment: what does `getPkRowReport` return?

Comment: It sounds like fill.travel is a nullable bool (`bool?`), and it is NULL in the database.

Comment: @driis, that's the answer, so you might as well move it down below.

Comment: If you want accurate help, provide the line that causes the error.

Comment: @DanielA.White It returns the pk of the selected record on the grid.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - I provided the line. Read my question from the start.

Comment: @driis You are right. I thought the record in the database was false and not null but I was incorrect. I am now manually assign travel to be false when i create the record so it will never be null. Also please post it as the answer and I will confirm. Thank You

Comment: 'what does getPkRowReport return?' -- that's not remotely relevant.

Comment: My comment was not about your question and was not answered anywhere -- it doesn't merit an answer. Perhaps you should stop shaking your head long enough to actually read what I wrote and understand it. Note especially that I quoted what someone else wrote.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can always switch to

```
 fill.travel.GetValueOrDefault()
```

To provide the default (false), or the value of the boolean column from the database. Or you can specify the default with an overload. Either way, the nullable currently doesnt have a value, which is why you get that exception.

Answer (score 17):

You are trying to access property from the nonexistent object (your fill.travel is null, and you calling prop from it), 
you can use coalesce operator (.Net 4.0):

```
bool travel = fill.travel ?? false;
```

Answer (score 7):

You will get a `InvalidOperationException` if you access the Nullable.Value property when the HasValue property is false.

Answer (score 6):

I had this happen because there was code like this:

```
bool? someVariable = (bool)someNullableBool;
```

The someNullableBool was null and this error was thrown.

The solution was to re-write it as:

```
bool? someVariable = (bool?)someNullableBool;
```

Comment: this right here was it. tried to cast a bool from a bool? on a class that didn't exist. Starting at me, right under my nose.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if nullable variable has some value like this before your actually access its value

```
if(fill.travel.HasValue)
{
   bool travel = fill.travel.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The value coming from the database is a nullable boolean.  When you call Nullable.Value, and the value is null, you will get this exception.  Consider checking the property Nullable.HasValue before calling .Value.

Answer (score 1):

Null is not false. See Eric Lippert's blog article series about this at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/03/26/null-is-not-false.aspx

You need to process a null result into a false, if that is how you want to translate it.

To make this case clear, consider this code:

```
bool travel;
bool? temptravel = fill.travel.Value;
if( temptravel == true )
    travel = true;
else
    travel = false;
```

Or just use Val Bakhtin's solution if you are using .Net 4

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the classic C ? operator like this:

```
bool travel = (fill.travel == null ? false : fill.travel.Value);
```