# When objects are check if it has null value prior to use why do I get Nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#, xamarin, nullable, crash-reports, xamarin.uwp

I always check nullable object that if it has value then only I try to access the value.

Having said that the issue still happens what could be the reason

Here is my crash report

> Exception Type:  System.InvalidOperationException Crashed Thread:  3
>
> Application Specific Information: Nullable object must have a value.
>
> Exception Stack:
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource
>   resource) System.Nullable`1.get_Value()
>   App.ViewModels.MyViewModel.d__154.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   App.UWP.DefectHistoryPage.d__5.MoveNext()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.b__6_0(Object
>   state)
>   System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
>   Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.UnhandledError.Propagate()
>   Microsoft.HockeyApp.Extensibility.Windows.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule.CoreApplication_UnhandledErrorDetected(Object
>   sender, UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs e)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nullable object must have a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555682/nullable-object-must-have-a-value)

Comment: null value errors can happen in library code that you're using - it doesn't have to be generated by user code

Comment: gotta see some code

Comment: its a big view model . I have one nullable variable and I am check using the method has value before checking the real value of the nullable variable ... I don't see any problem in debug build with that .. but in release build somehow I get a crash log

Answer (score 3):

> Nullable object must have a value

is a bit misleading. A nullable *can* be null.

The problem is when you try to access one of its properties. e.g. `var abc = yourNullable.SomeProperty;`.

Comment: I am checking if it has value then only I am accessing