# Nullable object must have a value C# Syncfusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, syncfusion, gantt-chart

I'm getting this error while trying to implement Gantt chart on asp .net.

I have already added my method and it's running in debugging mode and also not giving any information.

This is my code-behind; I'm using Stored procedures and I can't use direct SQL queries from the code.

What I'm trying to do is to invoke methods (SPs) from the database so I can make CRUD operations. Currently I have this but it doesn't render any info.

```
    using DSProyectosTableAdapters;
    using DSInformesProyectosTableAdapters;
    using Syncfusion.JavaScript.DataVisualization.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class ListarClientesProyectoGantt : clsUsuario
    {
        protected int idPagina = 1;
        protected string sConfSing = "Grafica Gantt";
        protected string sConfPlu = "Graficas Gantt";

        public int? Proyecto
        {
            get
            {
                int? id = null;
                int idAux;
                if (ViewState["idProyecto"] != null && ViewState["idProyecto"].ToString() != "" && int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["P"].ToString(), out idAux))
                    id = idAux;
                else
                {
                    if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys() && Request.QueryString["P"] != null && Request.QueryString["P"].ToString() != "" && int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["P"].ToString(), out idAux))
                    {
                        id = idAux;
                        this.Proyecto = id;
                    }
                    else if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
                    {
                        if (Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath != Request.Url.AbsolutePath && Request.UrlReferrer.Query != "")
                        {
                            Response.Redirect(string.Format("{0}{1}", Request.Url.AbsolutePath, Request.UrlReferrer.Query));
                        }
                    }
                }
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ViewState["idProyecto"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!this.Proyecto.HasValue)
                {
                       //     Response.Redirect("~/PnlCliente/ListarClientesProyectoGantt.aspx");
                }
            }
            catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
            {
                Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception TrackViewState )
            {
                msj.MostrarMensaje(3, TrackViewState.Message, TrackViewState );
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                msj.Visible = false;

                var MasterP = (Layout2)this.Master;
                MasterP.ConstruirMenu(idPagina, (int)Proyecto.Value, 4);

                this.GanttControl.DataSource = GetGanttData();
                this.GanttControl.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception TrackViewState)
            {
                msj.MostrarMensaje(2, TrackViewState.Message, TrackViewState);
            }
        }

        public class ActividadesInfo
        {


            public string TaskId { get; set; }
            public string TaskName { get; set; }
            public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
            public string ParentId { get; set; }
            public string Duration { get; set; }
            public string Progress { get; set; }
            public string Predecessor { get; set; }

        }

        public List<ActividadesInfo> GetGanttData()

        {

         sp_GanttTableAdapter DatosTA = new sp_GanttTableAdapter();

         DSProyectos.sp_GanttDataTable DatosT = DatosTA.GetDataIdProyecto(Proyecto);

            List<ActividadesInfo> list = new List<ActividadesInfo>();
            foreach (var DatosR in DatosT)
            {
            list.Add(new ActividadesInfo() { TaskId = DatosR.id.ToString(), ParentId =(DatosR.IsidPadreNull() ? 0 : DatosR.idPadre).ToString(), EndDate = DatosR.IsdFechaFNull() ? DateTime.Now : DatosR.dFechaF, StartDate = DatosR.IsdFechaINull() ? DateTime.Now : DatosR.dFechaI, Duration = "3", Predecessor = null, Progress = "100", TaskName = DatosR.sTitulo });

            }

            return list;
        }


    }


<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false" MasterPageFile="~/PnlCliente/Layout2.master" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableTheming="false" CodeFile="ListarClientesProyectoGantt.aspx.cs" Inherits="ListarClientesProyectoGantt" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphFiltro" runat="Server">
    <bit:mensajesv3 ID="msj" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHead" runat="Server">
    <link href="../App_Themes/samva/assets/syncfusion/Content/ejthemes/ej.widgets.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../App_Themes/samva/assets/syncfusion/Content/ejthemes/material/ej.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="../App_Themes/samva/assets/syncfusion/Scripts/ej/web/ej.web.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../App_Themes/samva/assets/syncfusion/Scripts/jsviews.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../App_Themes/samva/assets/syncfusion/Scripts/jsrender.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../App_Themes/samva/assets/syncfusion/Scripts/jquery.easing-1.3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">            

            function ActionComplete(args) {

                if (args.requestType == "indent" || args.requestType == "outdent" || args.requestType == "recordUpdate" || (args.requestType === 'save' && args.modifiedRecord) || args.requestType == "drawConnectorLine") {
                    var ganttRec = [];

                    if (args.requestType == "save")
                        ganttRec.push(args.modifiedRecord);
                    else if (args.requestType == "drawConnectorLine")
                        ganttRec.push(args.currentRecord);
                    else
                        ganttRec.push(args.data); 
                    if (args.updatedRecords && args.updatedRecords.length)
                        ganttRec = ganttRec.concat(args.updatedRecords);
                    updateModifiedGanttRecords(ganttRec);
                }

                else if (args.requestType == "save" && args.addedRecord) {
                    var data = args.addedRecord.item;
                    PageMethods.AddIt(data);


                    if (args.updatedRecords && args.updatedRecords.length)
                        updateModifiedGanttRecords(args.updatedRecords);
                }
                else if (args.requestType == "dragAndDrop") {
                    var ganttRec = [];
                    ganttRec.push(args.draggedRow);
                    if (args.updatedRecords && args.updatedRecords.length)
                        ganttRec = ganttRec.concat(args.updatedRecords);
                    updateModifiedGanttRecords(ganttRec);
                }


                else if (args.requestType == "delete") {
                    var data = args.data.item;
                    PageMethods.DeleteIt(data);
                    if (args.data.hasChildRecords) {
                        deleteChildRecords(args.data);
                    }
                    if (args.updatedRecords && args.updatedRecords.length)
                        updateModifiedGanttRecords(args.updatedRecords);
                }
            }

            function updateModifiedGanttRecords(records) {
                var modifiedRecord = [];
                if (records && records.length) {
                    var length = records.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
                        modifiedRecord.push(records[i].item);
                }
                PageMethods.UpdateIt(modifiedRecord);
            }


            function deleteChildRecords(record) {
                var childRecords = record.childRecords,
                    length = childRecords.length,
                    count, currentRecord;
                for (count = 0; count < length; count++) {
                    currentRecord = childRecords[count];
                    var data = currentRecord.item;
                    PageMethods.DeleteIt(data);
                    if (currentRecord.hasChildRecords) {
                        deleteChildRecords(currentRecord);
                    }
                }
            }



        </script>
    </asp:Content>
```

This is my .aspx. I don't know if I  have mapped all the necessary fields correctly in my aspx file.

Any suggestion or help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContenido" runat="Server">

        <ej:Gantt ID="GanttControl" runat="server" AllowSelection="True" DateFormat="M/dd/yyyy"
                TaskNameMapping="TaskName" StartDateMapping="StartDate" AllowDragAndDrop="true"
                EndDateMapping="EndDate" ProgressMapping="Progress" ParentTaskIdMapping="ParentId" DurationMapping="Duration"
                ScheduleStartDate="01/26/2019" ScheduleEndDate="03/20/2019" PredecessorMapping="Predecessor"
                TreeColumnIndex="1" AllowGanttChartEditing="true" ActionComplete="ActionComplete" EnableContextMenu="true">
                <dragtooltip showtooltip="true" />
       <editsettings allowediting="true" allowadding="true" allowdeleting="true" allowindent="true" editmode="normal" rowposition="Child"  />
       </ej:Gantt>



    </asp:Content>
```

[This is the line where is ocurring the breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZBWW.png)

Comment: Where in your code is this exception occurring? Also, see this...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555682/nullable-object-must-have-a-value

Comment: yeah ! when im trying to render the info to the frontend

Comment: Ummm I meant more like what line of code, which method. You know the sorts of things you have to figure out when debugging code.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            msj.Visible = false;

            var MasterP = (Layout2)this.Master;
            MasterP.ConstruirMenu(idPagina, (int)Proyecto.Value, 4);

            this.GanttControl.DataSource = GetGanttData();
            this.GanttControl.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception TrackViewState)
        {
            msj.MostrarMensaje(2, TrackViewState.Message, TrackViewState);
        }
    }

Comment: at this point of the code is when my ex breaks and throws the error

Comment: Are you familiar with breakpoints? You need to isolate the **exact** line of code that is failing, not the method where the error is. You need to step through this in the debugger.

Comment: yes i have attached the jpg wich shows the line where the code crashes

Comment: That is NOT the line where this fails. That is the first line in the method where this fails. You have several lines of code and at least two methods that you wrote that execute in the page load method. You have to step through the code (default is F10). Find out where the error is happening. Get the error message!!! Nobody can just look at your code and magically understand where the problem is. We need to know where it fails and what the message is to even get started.

Answer (score 0):

We checked the code snippet shared by you. And we note that, id(null) value is assigned to Proyecto. And in the Page_Init method, this.Proyecto.HasValue condition was checked. We cannot blindly check HasValue of nullable variable. Please check the null condition before proceeding.

```
public int? Proyecto
    {
        get
        {
           int? id = null;
             //...
            else
            {
             //... 
               {
           this.Proyecto = id;
                }
                //...
            }
            return id;
        }

    }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!this.Proyecto.HasValue)
            {
                //     
            }
        }
   //...
    }
```