# EF Core - Getting 'Nullable object must have a value' Exception In LINQ Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following query which includes a left join. I I guess when there are no records in the second table, the average throws a 'Nullable object must have a value' exception. How can I fix it?

```
List<int> averages = await
    (from x in ctx.X
        join y in ctx.Y on x.Id equals y.XId into j
        from xy in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where x.clientId == 5
        group xy by x.Magnitude into g
        orderby g.Key
        select (int)g.Average(x => x.SomeFloatValue)
        )
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nullable object must have a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555682/nullable-object-must-have-a-value)

Comment: What is the CLR (C#) type of the `SomeFloatValue`? e.g. `double`, `float` or ? also nullable or not?